# How to create a MySQL query which returns a row depending on existing field value?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
id    site_id    language_id    paragraph
 1          1              1    french text
 2          1              2    english text
 3          2              1    french text 
 4          2              3    spanish text
```

I want to make query returning paragraph giving the site_id language_id like:

```
SELECT paragraph FROM mytable WHERE site_id = givenSite AND
language_id =
if exists language_id = givenLanguage then givenLanguage
else if exists language_id = 2 then 2
else 1
```

I got something working like below but I hope we can write a better query:

```
DECLARE @site int, $language int  
SET @site = 1  
SET @language = 3  

SELECT CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS(SELECT paragraph_0
                  FROM   tablename
                  WHERE  language_id = @language AND site_id = @site)
              THEN (SELECT paragraph_0
                    FROM   tablename 
                    WHERE  language_id = @language AND site_id = @site)
              ELSE (
                SELECT CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT paragraph_0
                            FROM   tablename
                            WHERE  language_id = 2 AND site_id = @site)
                THEN (SELECT paragraph_0
                      FROM   tablename 
                      WHERE  language_id = 2 AND site_id = @site)
                ELSE (SELECT paragraph_0
                      FROM   tablename 
                      WHERE  language_id = 1 AND site_id = @site)
                END)
END
```

I tried to write [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c5fd4/8) but sorry, I didn't understand how to declare variables in sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
SELECT paragraph_0, IF(language_id = givenLanguage, 1, 0) AS isGivenLanguage
FROM tablename 
WHERE site_id = 3 AND language_id IN (1, 2, givenLanguage)
ORDER BY isGivenLanguage DESC, language_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure it works well. I tried here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c5fd4/29, with the given values, it should return 'Spanish text' if didn't make a mistake.

Comment: @caBBAlainB Rewrote my query, missed, that you have 2 default languages

Comment: oh good and even better than @Abhik proposal as it allows to english's id to have any value. This is my prefered solution even if Abhik's one works in some given hypothesis. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76d18/1  good match ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.

```
set @site := 1 ;
set @language := 3  ;
select
language_id,paragraph_0 from (
  select language_id,paragraph_0 from tablename where site_id =@site and language_id = @language
  union 
  select language_id,paragraph_0 from tablename where site_id =@site and language_id <> @language
)x
order by language_id desc limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c5fd4/20

Better using raking system

```
set @site := 1 ;
set @language := 3  ;
select
rank,paragraph_0 from (
  select 0 as rank, paragraph_0 from tablename where site_id =@site and language_id = @language
  union 
  select rank,paragraph_0 from(
    select @rn:= @rn+1 as rank ,paragraph_0 , language_id
    from tablename,(select @rn:=0)x where site_id =@site and language_id <> @language
    order by language_id desc 
  )x
)x
order by rank limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c5fd4/24

From the comments

> For example if I'm looking for language 5 of site 3. As searched
>   language doesn't exist it should look for english but english doesn't
>   exist it should return french which mandatory exists

This would be pretty simple as below, and looks like you already figured it out.

```
set @site := 1 ;
set @language := 3  ;

select
language_id,paragraph_0 from (
  select language_id,paragraph_0 from tablename where site_id =@site and language_id = @language
  union 
  select language_id,paragraph_0 from tablename where site_id =@site and language_id = 2
  union 
  select language_id,paragraph_0 from tablename where site_id =@site and language_id = 1
)x
order by language_id desc limit 1;
```

Comment: maybe I didn't explain well what I'm expecting for but none of your solution is ok. For example if I'm looking for language 5 of site 3. As searched language doesn't exist it should look for english but english doesn't exist it sould return french which mandatory exists. It seems it's the only query which fails. I didn't really understand the second method but I got the first one working propermy I think  by modifying it a bit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c5fd4/43

Comment: So you may always have either `english` or `french` of `language_id` 2 and 1 respectively if other language is not available ?

Comment: Right the my assumption was always finding a language by not knowing its weight, so the 2nd query I had does it, i.e. first check if the given data is available and give it `rank = 0` then find rest all languages order by the `language_id desc` and give them rank as `1,2..` and finally get one out of the union with rank in ascending order. As you explained now it would be done with just 3 unions and you already did :)

Comment: Yes Abhik language ids are taken in an existing reference table and will have these ids, it won't change. Then I'm sure there will have at least paragraph_0 in french, hopefully in english and maybe in any other language. So, if anybody asks to read it in it's own language, I try to find it, if no in english, if no, in french. Thanks a lot.